# Can a Google Glass application have menu buttons like an Android app?

Tags: button, menu, google-glass

Can a Google Glass application have menu buttons like an Android app?

Comment: Which menu buttons would you be referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're referring to buttons that bring up context menus, etc in your app and you're loading your application on to the device directly rather than using the Mirror API.

**Can it have buttons like a "standard" Android app?** It's just Android so you can do whatever you want. At I/O 2013 there was a demo of running a regular Android app on Glass. A bluetooth keyboard was used to send input.

**Should it have buttons like a "standard" Android app?** The answer is probably no, because Glass provides a somewhat different interaction paradigm than a phone.